I keep getting 'function not iterable' error with Pandas DataFrame filter, but same function works with apply. What am I missing?
TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable
I keep getting this error when I feel that the filter function should achieve my desired result.
What am I missing when I decide to use 'filter', (which to me looks neater than using 'loc' to achieve the same  outcome), and almost always end up with this error.
Here's a simple example.
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(4,4), columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
df.filter(lambda x:x['b'] > 0.5, axis=1)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  Cell In[190], line 1
    df.filter(lambda x:x['b'] > 0.5, axis=1)

  File ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py:5454 in filter
    return self.reindex(**{name: [r for r in items if r in labels]})

TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable

In [1]: df.apply(lambda x:x['b'] > 0.5, axis=1)
Out[1]: 
0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
dtype: bool


In [2]: df.loc[df['b']> 0.5]
Out[2]: 
          a        b         c         d
0  0.578342  0.82178  0.414652  0.630859
1  0.181232  0.91806  0.772260  0.502921


Even the most basic lambda function creates an error, e.g.:
In [5]: tru = lambda x: True

In [6]: df['b'].filter(tru)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  Cell In[196], line 1
    df['b'].filter(tru)

  File ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py:5454 in filter
    return self.reindex(**{name: [r for r in items if r in labels]})

TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable

# Once again

In [7]: df['b'].apply(tru)
Out[7]: 
0    True
1    True
2    True
3    True
Name: b, dtype: bool

In my mind, filter requires a function to return a bool, which the simplistic example clearly does, yet filter fails and again apply works. What is there 'under the hood' that makes the difference in outcome?
As explained above, I tried df.filter(function) which failed, yet
df.loc[df.apply(function)] yields the correct result.

This is a invalid use of the function filter you are using the filter function of the class Dataframe and the filter does not accept a function as its param(like the lambda function you are passing) look at the documentation of how filter works on a dataframe
do note this is not the filter function of a typical list (built in filter function that works on any iterable) you see in python that is different.
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html

df.filter is used to "[s]ubset the dataframe rows or columns according to the specified index labels".
E.g., df.filter on index labels gets you the appropriate subset:
df.filter([0,1], axis=0)

          a         b         c         d
0  0.550798  0.708148  0.290905  0.510828
1  0.892947  0.896293  0.125585  0.207243

Same with column labels:
df.filter(['c', 'd'], axis=1)

          c         d
0  0.290905  0.510828
1  0.125585  0.207243
2  0.029876  0.456833
3  0.676255  0.590863

To perform the kind of filter you want to achieve, one normally uses boolean indexing:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(3) # for reproducibility
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(4,4), columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])

cond = df['b'] > 0.5

df[cond]

          a         b         c         d
0  0.550798  0.708148  0.290905  0.510828
1  0.892947  0.896293  0.125585  0.207243

In your example at least, df.query could be an alternative:
df.query('b > 0.5')

          a         b         c         d
0  0.550798  0.708148  0.290905  0.510828
1  0.892947  0.896293  0.125585  0.207243


Possible confusions

Python's built-in filter

Using python's built-in filter requires an iterable, and a pd.DataFrame is not itself an iterable. E.g., you would have to use something like df.iterrows and then rebuild the df afterwards:
pd.DataFrame([row[1] for row in filter(lambda x: x[1]['b'] > 0.5, 
                                       df.iterrows())], 
             columns=df.columns)

          a         b         c         d
0  0.550798  0.708148  0.290905  0.510828
1  0.892947  0.896293  0.125585  0.207243

As you can see, this is a rather absurd thing to do.

df.groupby.filter

Somewhat confusingly, this function works differently from df.filter and has a different purpose, namely to filter entire groups on one or more group-wise conditions.
E.g., if we split our df into two groups: indices 0, 2, 3 vs 1, we can do something like this:
df.groupby([1,2,1,1]).filter(lambda x: (x['b'] > 0.5).all())

          a         b         c         d
1  0.892947  0.896293  0.125585  0.207243

# row `0` will be filtered out, since other group members fail test

Bear in mind that groupby.filter is often not the most efficient option, especially when dealing with simple aggregations. E.g., consider this:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0) # for reproducibility

N = 10_000

data = {'a': np.random.choice(np.arange(500), size=N, replace=True),
        'b': np.random.rand(N)}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

gr_transform = lambda df: df[df.groupby('a')['b'].transform('count') > 20]
gr_filter = lambda df: df.groupby('a').filter(lambda x: x['b'].count() > 20)

gr_filter(df).equals(gr_transform(df))
# True

%timeit gr_transform(df)
# 746 µs ± 23.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)

%timeit gr_filter(df)
# 30.5 ms ± 731 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

Here, groupby.transform with boolean indexing easily outperforms groupby.filter.

Note that you could use df.loc[lambda x: x['b'] > 0.5] to act like python's filter ;)

@ouroboros & @ Paul Wilson, Ahh. Yes you are right. But not confusing with python's 'filter' but with pandas gruopby filter. With a group I can do things like grp.filter(lambda x: x['b'].count() > 2) assuming there's been a grouping made. But it always requires that there's an aggregating function

I'll accept your answer since it covers at least 2 (correct) alternatives, using loc or query.

@JohnTweed: I see. Yes, that is a bit confusing. Restructured my A a bit to put the potential confusions at the end, adding df.groupby.filter and then its potential performance issue. Hope that's useful.

filter does not take a function. You should use loc[]
filter has a few options in pandas, but these are based on filtering the names of columns (or index), not the values. It cannot take a function as an argument. Instead, it would take an iterable, for example a list (there are other options in the documentation, but they're based on the same premise).
Ref
Pandas documentation
